# Reset Rank Per Group After Specific Action

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a dataframe like this

```
data = [(("ID1", "T1", "action_1")), 
        (("ID1", "T2", "action_2")),
        (("ID1", "T3", "action_3")),
        (("ID1", "T4", "SUCCESS")),
        (("ID1", "T5", "action_5")),
        (("ID1", "T6", "action_6")),
       (("ID1", "T7", "SUCCESS")),
       (("ID1", "T8", "action_7")),
       (("ID1", "T9", "action_8")),]
df = spark.createDataFrame(data, ["ID", "Timestamp", "Action"])
df.show()

+---+---------+--------+
| ID|Timestamp|  Action|
+---+---------+--------+
|ID1|       T1|action_1|
|ID1|       T2|action_2|
|ID1|       T3|action_3|
|ID1|       T4| SUCCESS|
|ID1|       T5|action_5|
|ID1|       T6|action_6|
|ID1|       T7| SUCCESS|
|ID1|       T8|action_7|
|ID1|       T9|action_8|
+---+---------+--------+
```

Within each group I want to rank the column `Action`. However the ranking should reset after it encounters a specific action. In this case it is the value `SUCCESS`

Expected output is

```
+---+---------+--------+----+
| ID|Timestamp|  Action|Rank|
+---+---------+--------+----+
|ID1|       T1|action_1|   1|
|ID1|       T2|action_2|   2|
|ID1|       T3|action_3|   3|
|ID1|       T4| SUCCESS|   4|
|ID1|       T5|action_5|   1|
|ID1|       T6|action_6|   2|
|ID1|       T7| SUCCESS|   3|
|ID1|       T8|action_7|   1|
|ID1|       T9|action_8|   2|
+---+---------+--------+----+
```

Any pointers how can I achieve this?

Comment: so you want to add incremental value in the rank column and reset if it encounters the _success string. is that right?

Comment: yes that is correct, per group

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hardik,

You need to use Window functions for this purpose.

The idea is to create an extra column, say `nbSuccessFound`, used to create your sub-groups. It will be computed by a cumulative sum, conditioned by the previous line's value.

Something like this should do the trick (tested in scala, but will be very close/identical in pyspark) :

```
val df = Seq(
  ("ID1", "T1", "action_1"),
  ("ID1", "T2", "action_2"),
  ("ID1", "T3", "action_3"),
  ("ID1", "T4", "SUCCESS"),
  ("ID1", "T5", "action_5"),
  ("ID1", "T6", "action_6"),
  ("ID1", "T7", "SUCCESS"),
  ("ID1", "T8", "action_7"),
  ("ID1", "T9", "action_8")
).toDF("ID", "Timestamp", "Action")
  .withColumn("nbSuccessFound", sum(when(lag(col("Action"),1).over(Window.partitionBy("ID").orderBy("Timestamp")) === lit("SUCCESS"),1).otherwise(0)).over(Window.partitionBy("ID").orderBy("Timestamp")))
  .withColumn("Rank", rank().over(Window.partitionBy("ID", "nbSuccessFound").orderBy("Timestamp")))


df.show(false)

+---+---------+--------+--------------+----+
|ID |Timestamp|Action  |nbSuccessFound|Rank|
+---+---------+--------+--------------+----+
|ID1|T1       |action_1|0             |1   |
|ID1|T2       |action_2|0             |2   |
|ID1|T3       |action_3|0             |3   |
|ID1|T4       |SUCCESS |0             |4   |
|ID1|T5       |action_5|1             |1   |
|ID1|T6       |action_6|1             |2   |
|ID1|T7       |SUCCESS |1             |3   |
|ID1|T8       |action_7|2             |1   |
|ID1|T9       |action_8|2             |2   |
+---+---------+--------+--------------+----+
```

Comment: I am unable to understand, why did you use sum at the end?

Comment: The ``sum`` aggregation is used to run a cumulative sum over your partition (ID), sorted by Timestamp and conditioned by the previous Action, so it will only be incremented if the previous Action was a Success. It allows us to obtain the proper ``nbSuccessFound`` column